# Can't override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, adminhtml, grid, widget

I've been searching for a possible answer to this, and my eyeballs are blurry. I want to override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox, and have written a class:

```
class MyModule_MyProject_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox
```

My config file entry for this is:

```
<blocks>  
  <adminhtml>  
    <rewrite>  
      <widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>
         MyModule_MyProject_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox  
      </widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>  
    </rewrite>  
  </adminhtml>  
</blocks>
```

I have other blocks overridden successfully, but this one won't drop into my code. Can anyone see something wrong with this? Can this renderer be subclassed?

Comment: Try putting the name of your class on the same line with the tag. Like this: `<widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>MyModule_MyProject_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox</widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>`

Comment: You don't get a "class not found" error? I thought Marius is right, I would try to remove the line breaks. But if this code "works"... Did you clean the cache?

Comment: It is inline in my code, I just broke it up for clarity here. As far as getting a class not found error, no, there's no error, just doesn't hit my class. No error, no logging, no nothing. I read something about some Magento classes not being override-able, could this be one of them?

Comment: It should be rewriteable. Perhaps a stupid question, but since we can't see the rest of your module: your module has a xml file in /app/etc/modules? When you purposely create a syntax error in the XML. Do you get an error (developer mode must be enabled). And like Fabian already stated, is your cache flushed or disabled.

Comment: The entire rest of the module is working, and working well. Thus, I do have a module.xml file in app/etc/modules. I have overridden many other classes in this module - this is the only one that doesn't seem to work. I have shortcut the thing by duplicating the checkbox renderer file in app/local/..., whereas the rest of my code is subclassed and renamed in app/community. Not the right way to do it, but the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: @blaviguer is this for normal gird check boxes or for something specific like the checkboxes on the product link grids?

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite this code:

```
  <widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>
     MyModule_MyProject_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox  
  </widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>
```

To:

```
  <widget_grid_column_renderer_massaction>
     MyModule_MyProject_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox  
  </widget_grid_column_renderer_massaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see unwanted spaces at this part and that is making problem here

```
  <widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>
     MyModule_MyProject_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox  
  </widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>
```

So use this code.

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>MyModule_MyProject_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox</widget_grid_column_renderer_checkbox>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

Dont forget to clear the cache after the update.